# Is it idiomatic to say “I've learned a lot”?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

I guess it is idiomatic to use "learned a lot" to express gratefulness.

And I found much more people using ["learned a lot"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22learned%20a%20lot%22) than ["have learned a lot"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22have%20learned%20a%20lot%22).

So, is it idiomatic to use "have learned a lot" to express gratefulness

Comment: "I learned a lot" at some time in the past. "I have learned a lot" through some experience or course of study that has recently finished - so, yes, you can say "I've learned a lot" to thank someone for teaching you.

Comment: @KateBunting For instance, someone answered my 
particular question on ELL, and then I can say "I've learned a lot" for teaching me, right? What about simple past tense, when to use it?

Comment: "I learned a lot on the course I took last year."

Comment: @KateBunting I've learned a lot in our discussion. Thanks for your excellent teaching. Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would use *I learned a lot* when speaking of the past - "I learned a lot on the course I took last year."

At least in British English, we would usually say *I have learned a lot* when speaking of a recent learning experience. "I've learned a lot since starting Mr X's course."